# Как отобразить справа картинку и слева блок?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать, чтобы к правому краю была прижата картинка, а слева от нее прижатый блок div?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/y39oycer/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

И блоку, и картинке дать `float:right;`.

А можно одному дать `float:left`, а второму `float:right;`.